# перенос приложения на GTK+ на другую машину

Tags: linux, gcc, gtk

Почему когда я компилирую программу на GTK+ в своей системе Linux, то всё работает, а когда переношу скомпилированный файл в другую систему Linux, то приложение не запускается?

> konsole: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.

---

1. `uname -mo` пишет `x86_64 GNU/Linux` (в той системе которой компилировал)
2. `uname -mo` пишет `i686 GNU/Linux` (в которую переносил)

вот файл: https://pastebin.com/q0Vn8hq2

компилировал так:

```
gcc main.c -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

скомпилировалось хорошо и на первой системе исправно заупустилось.

Comment: Скорее всего, это означает несовместимость архитектур. Например, попытка запустить бинарник для x86_64 на i686 системе. Добавьте в вопрос вывод `uname -mo` и `file ваш_бинарник`. А причём тут GTK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы скомпилировать исполняемый файл для i686 в системе с архитектурой x86_64, нужно добавить флаг компилятора `-m32`.

Может так статься, что для компиляции не окажется нужных библиотек. В таком случае придётся допоставить из репозиториев соответствующие библиотеки в систему, где происходит сборка. Например, в Ubuntu достаточно поставить пакет [gcc-multilib](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gcc-multilib).

Ещё также учтите, что помимо кросскомпилятора и 32-ухбитной стандартной библиотеки в сборочной системе надо иметь 32-ухбитную GTK. В той же самой убунте её можно установить так:

```
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev:i386
```

Кроме того, на компьютере, где вы будете запускать вашу программку, должен быть установлен GTK (как минимум пакет **libgtk-3-0**). При желании избежать установки зависимостей на принимающей стороне, собирайте программу статически, добавив флаг `--static` в вызове утилиты **pkg-config**. Помните, что статически собранные двоичные исполняемые файлы обычно бывают больше по размеру.